# PFRelation Deleting One Object From A PFRelation, Not All

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, parse-platform

Explanation of what's taking place:  The user has added a job as their favorite within another view.  Now the user is in the Favorites tab and decides that they no longer want the job as one of their favorites anymore, so they swipe to delete the job.  They tap the delete button and the errors below take place...the code works as is, but it also deletes every single job the user has saved as a favorite, instead of just deleting the one job.

My code also gives me an alert of:

**Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.**

```
#import "JobDetailViewController.h"
#import "MyFavoritesTableViewController.h"
#import "Parse/Parse.h"
#import "Job.h"
#import "JobListViewController.h"

@interface MyFavoritesTableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *mainTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *subTitle;

@end

@interface MyFavoritesTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyFavoritesTableViewController
{}

@synthesize mainTitle;
@synthesize subTitle;



- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
        // Custom the table

        // The className to query on
        self.parseClassName = @"Jobs";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        self.textKey = @"Position";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = YES;

        // The number of objects to show per page
        self.objectsPerPage = 30;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];


}
- (void)objectsWillLoad {
    [super objectsWillLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object: (PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *myJobsTableIdentifier = @"myFavsCell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myJobsTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:myJobsTableIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    PFFile *thumbnail = [object objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
    PFImageView *thumbnailImageView = (PFImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AppIcon.png"];
    thumbnailImageView.file = thumbnail;
    [thumbnailImageView loadInBackground];

    UILabel *positionLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
    positionLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Position"];
    UILabel *rotationLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:102];
    rotationLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Rotation"];
    UILabel *locationLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:103];
    locationLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Location"];
    UILabel *typeLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:104];
    typeLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Type"];
    return cell;

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetailedView"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        Job *job = [[Job alloc] init];

        JobDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        job.position = [object objectForKey:@"Position"];
        job.poc = [object objectForKey:@"POC"];
        job.email = [object objectForKey:@"Email"];
        job.phone = [object objectForKey:@"Phone"];
        job.apply = [object objectForKey:@"Apply"];
        job.imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
        job.rotation = [object objectForKey:@"Rotation"];
        job.location = [object objectForKey:@"Location"];
        job.type = [object objectForKey:@"Type"];
        job.clearance = [object objectForKey:@"Clearance"];
        job.job_description = [object objectForKey:@"Job_Description"];
        job.qualifications = [object objectForKey:@"Qualifications"];
        job.originalJob = object;
        destViewController.job = job;
    }
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if ([self.objects count] == indexPath.row) {
        [self loadNextPage];
    } else {
        PFObject *photo = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"%@", photo);

        // Do something you want after selected the cell
    }
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable

{
    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    PFRelation *relation = [user relationForKey:@"Favorites"];
    PFQuery *myquery = [relation query];
    if (self.pullToRefreshEnabled) {
        myquery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly;
    }
    return myquery;

}

#pragma mark - DeleteJobViewDelegate


    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    PFRelation *relation = [user relationForKey:@"Favorites"];
    PFQuery *myquery = [relation query];
    NSArray *array = [myquery findObjects];
        for (PFObject *object in array)
        {
                [relation removeObject:object];
        }

    [user saveInBackground];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
        [self loadObjects];
    }

    @end
```

Comment: For some reason, if you delete one job from Favorites, it deletes all the jobs from favorites.

Comment: In your loop u are deleting them all. Use saveEventually and that will remove the issue of the error.

Comment: @DogCoffee I changed [user saveInBackground]; to [user saveEventually]; and I am still getting the error.  As far as the loop are you referring to the "for" statement under the NSArray?

Comment: @DogCoffee debug manager is saying the error is originating from NSArray *array = [myquery findObjects];  How would I fix this?

Comment: Use this,         query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil { return }
        }

Comment: I also suggest subclassing PFObjects even PFUser. Makes life easier. Also.. in prepare for segue, I would pass the job object and in ViewDidLoad do all the setting of the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are removing all the objects from the Relation:

```
NSArray *array = [myquery findObjects];
for (PFObject *object in array)
{
    [relation removeObject:object];
}
```

What your code is doing is going though your array and removing each object from the relation.

What you want to do is to delete the job for that cell only. You can get that using the `indexPath`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    PFRelation *relation = [user relationForKey:@"Favorites"];

    [relation removeObject:[self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    [user saveInBackground];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self loadObjects];
}
```

Your second problem:

**Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread. Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.**

That warning is because `findObjects` is a synchronous call. You should use the `findObjectsInBackground` instead. But if you make the changes I gave above, you won't need it.

Comment: Probably a stupid question but I am getting an red error pointing to [relation removeObject:[self.objects objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row]];

saying that there is "No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'objectAtIndexPath'"

Comment: Sorry, my bad. See updated answer. It should be `objectAtIndex` instead of `objectAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I've been working on this for "DAYS" and you solved it in such a short amount of time!  Bravo!  Thank you!